# Arc Touch Mouse SE won't reconnect on 10.10, mods to blame?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

I have an Arc Touch Mouse SE (Bluetooth edition of the Arc Touch Mouse) and though I remember long ago it worked for the most part in 10.9, it doesn't seem to work in 10.10 and I'm trying to determine if it's one of the 'mods' I've installed that are to blame.

Here's how it works right now: I have to delete it from Bluetooth preferences if it exists already, and manually pair the mouse to get it to work. It will work until I turn either it or Bluetooth off, then it'll refuse to connect until I repeat this process.

I've done, for testing, a clean install of 10.10 on an SD card to see if it's something I've installed that interferes with Bluetooth. It seems to work perfectly on this clean install.

Also, and this may be related, the mouse does not show up in USB Overdrive. It's not present on the list, and the settings I had set do not do anything to the mouse's behavior.

I suppose I should start by listing everything that shows up in the bottom pane of System Preferences. I wonder if there's anything else I have that might interfere with Bluetooth that doesn't show up here. Here's the list:

- Chrome Remote Desktop Host
- Flash Player
- HyperDock
- Java
- Line 6 Audio-MIDI Devices
- LinkLiar
- NI USB Audio
- NoSleep
- SwitchResX
- USB Overdrive
- Xbox 360 Controllers

Comment: probably not saving the preferences, so fix them in disk utility.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "fix them in disk utility".

Comment: I've run "Verify Disk Permissions" in Disk Utility, and it had no effect on the issue.

Comment: seems to be broken again in the 10.10.4 beta :(

Comment: Macbook Pro mid-2012, it will connect without a hitch on my windows 10 partition but not while running os x 10.10.5. The mac side can't even see it. Definitely OS X driver related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now confirm that the issue is a bug in OS X's Bluetooth implementation. The mouse connects just fine in 10.10.0, I hear it connects fine in 10.10.1, but has the issues I've been describing in 10.10.2.

I can also confirm that the issue has been fixed in the latest OS X 10.10.3 public beta.

Comment: I am now getting this exact thing on macOS Sierra

Answer (score 0):

I am running 10.10.4 on a mid 2010 iMac 27" and wish to let you know that the Microsoft Arc Bluetooth mouse is not even recognised using bluetooth properties, let alone synchronise. There seems to be a lot of forums describing issues with this mouse. Considering I just bought two whilst in the USA (for the iMac and my daughter's Macbook Air) I feel let down. :-(

Comment: My only guess as to why is that your iMac may not support Bluetooth LE (low energy), which the mouse uses and requires. It's a newer standard.